# Run python websockets application on IIS

Tags: python, iis, websocket

My goal is to run a python websockets application on IIS 10 (yep, it's weird a bit).

I use 'websockets' package (https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets) for this and my app looks like:

```py
import asyncio
import websockets

async def stub(websocket, path):
    while True:
        msg = await websocket.recv()
        await websocket.send('RESPONSE: ' + msg)

app = websockets.serve(stub, "localhost", 9010)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(app)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

On IIS I've:

- created new site that has binding to http://localhost:9010
- set up wfastcgi for this site and my app

When I try to connect to `ws://localhost:9010` I get an error `OSError: [Errno 10013] error while attempting to bind on address ('127.0.0.1', 9010)`
As I got it's related to that I've already bound port 9010 in IIS.

But if I change port in python app to another, i.e. `app = websockets.serve(stub, "localhost", 9011)`, and try to connect I got nothing (no error, no response).

Could anyone tell me please how I can change my app (or IIS settings) to get it worked?

Comment: No one maintains wfastcgi any more. Set up IIS as a reverse proxy for your Python server please, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing Or use HttpPlatformHandler.

Comment: @LexLi, thanks for idea, will try to do that way also!

Comment: Error 10013 This error is caused by Permission denied. Please try turning off your windows firewall then try again.

Comment: @samwu, I'm not sure that it's a problem of firewall. When I put any http site on 9010 port (i.e. simple flask app), it works correctly

Comment: Have you tried closing the firewall and then testing your application?